# What do these phrases 'get on the back' and 'bear it down' mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What do these phrases 'get on the back' and 'bear it down' mean in this context:

> M. I know what you are. You’re the Old Man of the Sea.
>   C. Who’s he?
>   M. The horrid old man Sinbad had to carry on his back. That’s what you are. You get on the back of everything vital, everything trying to be honest and free, and you bear it down.

From The Collector, by John Fowles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would appear to be a fairly simple metaphor.

If you "get on" a person's back, you climb onto their back.  You are a weight that is heavy and "bears them down". Look for the phrasal verbs "get on" and "bear down" in your dictionary.

Here it is used metaphorically: The person obstructs "everything vital (ie full of life)" and "trying to be honest and free"

The person makes other people feel unhappy or lifeless.

Comment: The phrasal verb "to bear something down" meaning "to overburden it, to crush it, to weigh it down, to overpower it, to subdue it" is not something I've ever *heard*, though I've seen it in texts from the 19th and 18th centuries.